# Export separate pdfs from SSRS generated report

Tags: reporting-services, pdf-generation, ssis-2012

Is it possible for SSRS to name and separate pdf exported files based on parameter groupings?  Right now, when I run the report, it only gives me one pdf with 100+ pages.  However, at every page-break, I'd like SSRS to create a new pdf file, and it'd be a real time-saver if it would also insert the pdf's filename based on the grouping selection.

Is this possible in SSRS, or do i need to use SSIS for this functionality?

I'm using 'Visual Studio 2010' for SSRS, and 'SQL Server 2012' for integration services

Comment: I think you should create a 1 page report and create a small application consuming SSRS WebService. Another option would be to split the 100+ page pdf to 100+ PDFs with another application, but you wouldn't have the custom names.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, what you ask is not possible in SSRS.

Comment: Found an easy solution.  I exported the SSRS generated report as an Excel spreadsheet, and using Excel's visual basic, ran a macro to generate each of the pdfs based on the report's groupings.  The formatting is a little off with the excel-to-pdf conversion, but i solved it by recording and running a formatting macro for all sheets in the workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be able to do all of what you want in SSRS - if you have the **Enterprise edition** that has **Data-Driven Subscriptions**.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150(v=sql.130).aspx

You would have a parameter for the grouping (your **page-break**) - for example UserID.

In your data-driven **query** (NOT the report but a different query used to fire the subscription), you would have a field for your grouping - your UserID in our example. Another field could have your ReportName that is derived from your data - ex.

```
UserID, 'ReportName for ' + UserName + ' on ' + GetDate() as ReportName
```

When the data-driven query runs, it will create a record for each UserID which in turn will fire a report for each UserID using it as the parameter to limit the report to just that userID. You could even have that report only e-mailed to that user.

There are ways to run data-driven subscritptions without the Enterprise Edition using SSIS but the do take a bit of work.

http://geoffbi.blogspot.com/2012/04/data-driven-subcriptions-in-standard.html