# SQL Server Reporting Services export separate PDFs from SSRS generated report subscriptions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

Is it possible for SSRS to name and separate `.pdf` exported file for each patient ID? Right now, when the report runs every morning, it only provides one `.pdf` with 50+ pages. However, at every page break, I'd like SSRS to create a new `.pdf` file, and it'd be a real time-saver if it would also insert the `.pdf`'s filename based on the grouping selection. I would need the `.pdf` saved in the format of `ReportName_PatientID1.pdf`, `ReportName_PatientID2.pdf` etc...

My dataset query is:

```
Select PatientID, Name, Address, date, Insurance, date filled 
from table A
```

Is this possible in SSRS, or do I need to use SSIS for this functionality?

Comment: Maybe this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871099/export-separate-pdfs-from-ssrs-generated-report

Comment: Yup, follow the instructions in manderson's link. You'll need to add a parameter for patient ID in your report. Then write a query that returns distinct ClientID. Use that query in your data driven subscription and it will make a report for each ClientID returned by your query. You can make another column in that data driven subscription for file name if just the client ID doesn't suit you and set that as the filename in the subscription as well.

Comment: I created a Parameter called PatientID in the report. then in the row groups, I did a group on a @patientid parameter. In the page groups, I selected 'between each instance of group''. The data-driven query is " Select PatientID, concat(letter, Patientid) as Filename  from Table A. "

This query has 20 Patient IDs, it is supposed to create 20 PDFs (one for each patient ID).

Instead, it creating 20 PDFs for the same patient ID. Please correct me.

Comment: Do you have the **Enterprise Edition** of SQL Server with data driven subscriptions? If not, there's another way but it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: How to determine whether my SQL is enterprise edition or not?

Comment: I just ran this query: SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')
and it gave me this below result

Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit)

Comment: At the bottom of your subscription page you should see Report Parameters. For your PatientID, set it to "Get value from dataset" and pick your patientID column in the drop down on the right.